# Design process of html to be used as template for a backend

Tags: html, css

I am converting mockups to HTML + CSS. Then this will be used as a template for a PHP system by other people (actually it can be any server side language, PHP is not important)

There are, for example, 10 different type of pages. But in each page, many blocks can differ in many cases. For example a block can be displayed differently for anonymous and logged in users. But I dont want to copy the whole html file and just change that block and have another html file. I know php can be written to include parts of the page from many files. But there is no php yet in my design workflow, and I want to have full HTML design before ever passing the files to PHP guys.

Basically, what I want is a "CASCADED" html structure for design purposes. So in a "container" html file, I can include all the different parts from different HTML files.

Does anyone know a method / tool / process to design dynamic pages?

Comment: I just create separate files for the different cases of blocks.  So if you have 3 different possible formats for the content, make 3 separate files one with each different format and name them accordingly.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I agree, it is good for handing the outputs to the developers, but how can you preview them in the browser?

Comment: I researched a bit about static HTML generators like Jekyll, etc. But I think they are a bit overkill for just designing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of accomplishing this.  First pull in each of the various components on the page with ajax calls, jquery will make this relatively easy.

Or if you don't want to use javascript then iframes.  But the iframes method is extremely prone to buggyness and in some layouts just will not work.  Also keep in mind that since you aren't directly injecting html into the page each page would have to keep track of its own styles.

Comment: iframes doesnt get the css applied to the master page, so they are useless for me. I also tried <object> tag but also it creates problems with css.